# substr() in php doesn't index past '<' html tags

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do a very simple procedure.

I have a string:

```
$str = 'i am a div <div>hello</div>';
```

When i use substr to get a slice of the str:

```
echo substr($str,0,1) // i
echo substr($str,0,2) // i
echo substr($str,0,3) // i a
echo substr($str,0,4) // i am
echo substr($str,0,5) // i am
echo substr($str,0,6) // i am a
echo substr($str,0,7) // i am a
echo substr($str,0,8) // i am a <
echo substr($str,0,9) // i am a             <- what is going on here, lost the '<'?
```

I have noticed that substr doesn't find any character after the `<` literal. So from index 9 to the end it will always print `i am a` . Why is this and how can i get around this?

I want to get up to the `>` of the opening tag. so:

```
echo substr($str,0,15) // output => i am a div <div>
```

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars(...);`

Comment: If you're displaying the output on an HTML page, you're creating invalid HTML when you echo `<` without `>`.

Comment: @IłyaBursov I tried this with image tags and now when i echo my image tag, it just prints out the link. so i have an achor tag rapped around a image tag. It showed the image, but now it just shows the link. How do i get it to show the image.

Answer (score 1):

> use this :

```
$str = htmlspecialchars('i am a div <div>hello</div>');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with substr(), it actually does the job, the reason why you can't see the result is because you are testing it out on the browser, when echoing the output inside the browser try to filter it first with `echo htmlentities(substr($str,0,15));`.

I tried you code on the terminal and outputs the following

```php
// phptest.php
<?php

$str = 'i am a div <div>hello</div>';


for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($str) + 1; $i++) {
    echo substr($str, 0, $i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

```sh
# terminal
$ > php phptest.php
i
i
i a
i am
i am
i am a
i am a
i am a d
i am a di
i am a div
i am a div
i am a div <
i am a div <d
i am a div <di
i am a div <div
i am a div <div>
i am a div <div>h
i am a div <div>he
i am a div <div>hel
i am a div <div>hell
i am a div <div>hello
i am a div <div>hello<
i am a div <div>hello</
i am a div <div>hello</d
i am a div <div>hello</di
i am a div <div>hello</div
i am a div <div>hello</div>
```

see there's nothing wrong with substr(), it's in your browser, because it reads it as an invalid Html, that why all character starts from `<` doesn't render by the browser